# Deploying ASP.Net MVC Website without installing MsSql Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have developed a website for small business owners. 
So, Is it possible to run a website on the client's machine without installing the MsSql Server?
Is there any other tool that performs all operations that a published website requires.

Currently, I am installing MsSql on Clent's machine. But by this method, my Database design can be easily copied.

I would like to quickly install my web application on the Client's machine. and also hide the database if possible. So, Suggest all possible ways by which installation becomes quick.

Comment: Hi. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask prior to ask a question.

Comment: What makes you think SQL Server is a requirement for an ASP.NET MVC site? It's only a requirement if you actually code your site to use SQL Server. There's plenty of other database systems besides SQL Server. And besides, you typically put your database server on a different machine than your web server.

Comment: @mason I have developed a website using Ms SQL so it's necessary to install Ms SQL server. 
One more thing, Read Question Carefully, I have also stated that I want to run that website locally so, why should I install it on another system?

Comment: Because SQL Server is a notorious resource hog, and having it on the same machine as your web server is going to result in bad performance. If you don't want your customers to be able to access the database, the proper thing to do is create a Software as a Service (SaaS) application and run it in the cloud.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

First, I should say that unless you own the computer or server you are installing on it will be very difficult to hide database design, Data can be encrypted but the design will be accessible by the administrator of the computer. If you own the computer or server you can install the MVC site in a Kiosk type situation where only you have access to the system.

SQL Server Compact might be a good fit for what you would like to do, you can encrypt it as a file. you can also place restrictions on permissions to the access. there is a lot you can do with it and research is required.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2008/05/14/security-and-encryption-for-sql-server-compact/

Now you could build the MVC application to use Jason. You can encrypt the content of the JSON file using AES encryption. You will need to define a key that will be used for encryption and decryption.